# Why use "include ::X" instead of "include X"?

Tags: ruby, syntax, include

In some codes I see this:

```
include ActiveModel::ClassFoo
```

and in some codes I see this:

```
include ::ActiveModel::ClassFoo
```

What is the difference? 
Sorry I had no clue what to Google for to find the answer to this.

Comment: no difference, `::` at the very left just change the scope to the top.

Comment: @oldergod : "just change the "scope" to the top" ... sorry I didn't understand what you meant. Can you explain it more details.thanks.

Comment: I.e., start name resolution at the "top" of the namespaces.